# Rounding up/down to the nearest 5 minutes where hh:mm:ss value is in varchar form

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a database which one column has a hr:min:sec value like "14:04:33" as varchar (50). I want to round up/down to the nearest 5 min: 14:05:00 and 14:00:00 respectively and both of them needs to be varchar(50). I tried to round up by converting them to datetime and the code I used to round down to the nearest 5 min was:

```
DECLARE @Time varchar (50)
SELECT @Time ='14:04:33'
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(datetime,(FLOOR(CAST(CONVERT(datetime,@Time,108)As float )*288)/288), 108)AS varchar (50))
```

however the final output is Jan 1 1900 2:00 PM

and the code I used to round up to the nearest 5 min was:

```
DECLARE @Time varchar (50)
SELECT @Time ='14:04:33'
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(datetime,(CEILING(CAST(CONVERT(datetime,@Time,108)As float)*288)/288), 108) AS varchar(50))
```

And the final output is Jan 1 1900 2:05 PM. I am looking for a suitable function for conversion in **sql server 2012**.

Comment: So, not only is it [varchar](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type), but it's way larger than it needs to be?  Best end result is to store it as, ya know, an actual [time column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

Floor Value --

```
DECLARE @Time varchar (50)
SELECT @Time ='14:04:33'
SELECT CONVERT(time,CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(HH,@Time))+':'+CONVERT(varchar(2),(DATEPART(MI,@Time)-DATEPART(MI,@Time)%5))+':00')
```

Ceil Value --

```
DECLARE @Time varchar (50)
SELECT @Time ='14:04:33'
SELECT DATEADD(MI,5,CONVERT(time,CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(HH,@Time))+':'+CONVERT(varchar(2),(DATEPART(MI,@Time)-DATEPART(MI,@Time)%5))+':00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL 2012, you can use the new date & time functions. This way will round down to the nearest 5 minutes:

```
DECLARE @When VARCHAR(50) = '14:22:33'
DECLARE @Time TIME = CAST(@When AS TIME)

SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS
(
    DATEPART(HOUR, @Time), --Hour
    DATEPART(MINUTE, @Time) / 5 * 5, --Minute
    0, --Second
    0, --Fraction
    0 --Precision
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx